# focusout not triggering on iPhone

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script that if you ex input "61" in an input field, it should round up to "63", and it should show an overlay/div (tooManyFrameprofiles or WrongNumberFrameprofiles), however it doesn't seem to trigger the "focusout" event on an iPhone or Android... It works perfectly in a desktop browser...

The script looks like:

```
$(document).delegate("input.product-quantity-meter", "focusout", function () {

                var number = $(this).val();

                if (parseFloat(number) > 90) {
                    $("body").append("<div class='modal-backdrop fade in'></div>")
                    $("#tooManyFrameProfiles").removeClass("hide fade");
                }

                $("button.without").hide();
                $("button.with").show();

                //Check if number is divisable by 3
                if (number % 3 == 0) {
                    var quantity = number / 3;
                    $("input.product-quantity").val(quantity);
                    var quantityNumber = $("input.product-quantity").val();
                }
                else {
                    // If not diviable by 3, round up number 
                    roundedNumber = round_up(number, 3)

                    $("body").append("<div class='modal-backdrop fade in'></div>")

                    $("#wrongNumberFrameProfiles").removeClass("hide fade");
                    $(this).val(roundedNumber);

                    var quantity = roundedNumber / 3;
                    $("input.product-quantity").val(quantity);
                }
                $("button.close").on('click', function () {
                    $(".modal-backdrop").remove();
                    $("#wrongNumberFrameProfiles").addClass("hide fade");
                    $("#tooManyFrameProfiles").addClass("hide fade");

                    $("button.without").hide();
                    $("button.with").show();
                });
            });
```

Comment: Try `.on('blur', '.selector', function () {`

Comment: Doenst work, It never catches the .on event

Comment: Im doing it like this: $(document).on('blur', '.input.product-quantity-meter', function () {

Comment: what version of jquery are you using?

Comment: using 1.9.1 or higher, `.on` should work

Comment: @Omar it works on 1.8 too

Comment: @roasted just to be on the safe side. as he mentioned it doesn't catch '`.on` event.